# CreateProcess() compiling error?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to figure out how to use the CreateProcess() function, and i'm not too proficient in C++. i've tried a few things to try making the error go away, but then it appears that the application doesn't do what i expect it to do thereafter.

what I want to do is pass "cmd.exe /c ipconfig > C:\test.txt" to it and have it execute that as expected.

the errors that i'm getting (in dev C++) are:

> 6 C:\Dev-Cpp\project\test\Untitled1.cpp `main' must return`int'
>   C:\Dev-Cpp\project\test\Untitled1.cpp In function `int main(...)': 
>   28 C:\Dev-Cpp\project\test\Untitled1.cpp return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int'

any help would be greatly appreciated.

here's the code i'm using (taken from microsoft's example):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }


    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );     
}
```

Comment: @DAXaholic, any particular reason you removed the existing tag?

Comment: Because the problem has nothing to do with the API for creating a process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )`

to

`int _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )`

and return an exit code in your program, that is, change

```
{
    printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}
```

to

```
{
    printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    return 1;
}
```